Is there a limitation on the number of recipients this plugin can send?
We want to use this Email Extension jenkins plugin to send notifications to potentially thousands or even tens of thousands of users. Our plan is to print these emails in the Console Output and use regex to serve it into the Project Recipient List parameter.
Is it even feasible based on the potential huge number of recipients?
Thank you in advance for any recommendations!
I have not tried to send to these many users so not sure
